# Export table to CSV - string formatting issue into separate cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, csv

I have several HTML tables that I want to allow the user to export its content to a csv.

I currently have this solution implemented and it almost works perfectly:

```
function exportTableToCsv($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td,th)'),

        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11),
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0),

        colDelim = ' ',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td,th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace('"', '""');

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + ' ',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
$(".ExportSummary").on('click', function () {
    exportTableToCsv.apply(this, [$('#SummaryTable'), 'ExportSummary.csv']);
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mu5g1a7x/1/)

---

Now, **my issue is** that I cannot get the string formatting to work by putting the `<td>` in separate cells in Excel. I simply don't know how to get the text to be placed in separated cells since it is being mapped together into a whole string content.

I want the desired output that is provided with this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/xhYcD/) - but this solution does not provide the ability to choose filename and setting the appropiate content-type (application/csv) to be recognized by the browser.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example

USA/UK CSV file the decimal separator is a period/full stop and the value separator is a comma.
European CSV/DSV file the decimal separator is a comma and the value separator is a semicolon

I have modified a little bit your script:

```
function exportTableToCsv($table, filename) {
...
        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = ';',
        rowDelim = '\r\n',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td,th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();
             ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mu5g1a7x/2/

Let me know, if I understood you correctly.